# Do we need STUN server after send first message in WebRTC procession?

Tags: webrtc, stun, ice-protocol

Do we need to use ***STUN server*** everytime when we want to send a media    message to other device or just use it in the first time?

Because after we send first message, we've known our public IP address.

I mean if we just need ***STUN server*** for the first time (to get Public Ip Address) so we don't care anything if ***STUN server*** down during we    transfer the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean WebRTC connection is established when you say "sending first message", if that's the case then no, STUN server is needed only when you are generating ICE candidates, it provides the public IP of your peer, and it not involved in text/media communication between peers once the connection is established.

Comment: So after the connection is establlished and STUN server down. We still can transfer the media message and don't care about that, right?

Comment: @BuiQuangHuy you mean whether the video call wont be interrupted? then, yes.

Comment: but remember, new peers trying to establish peer connection might fail if STUN server is down

Comment: Yes, because in my question, I asked do we "need" STUN server after the connection is established? and you say yes, so I confuse @@